# How to create a sql table from a csv file?

Tags: sql-server, powershell-5.0

Given a `.csv` file, `Fact.csv`, that lets say has 7 columns

The ultimate goal is to have something like this:

```
script.ps1 Fact.csv 3 4
```

in which the first 3 columns are for sure a `varchar` type, while the rest of the columns (4) are `real` type.

How do I loop through the headers of the `.csv` file (which can contain data but we don't want to import the data, just the headers for the column names of the table), and create the table (the name of the `.csv` file, e.g. `Fact`) along with the table columns dynamically, with the column types as specified above by the numbers in a database?

pseudocode:

```
$csvfile = .\Fact.csv
$csv = Import-CSV $csvFile
$csvHeaders = ($csv | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty).name

Function Query($Query) {
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection 
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$Server;Initial Catalog=$Database;Integrated Security=SSPI" 
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand 
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection 
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $Query 
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter 
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd 
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet 
$a=$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$SqlConnection.Close() 
$DataSet.Tables[0] }

foreach ($column in $csvHeaders | where 1st $x columns = varchar and remaining columns = real) {
Query "CREATE TABLE [dbo].[$csvfile.name](
    [column1] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [column2] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [column3] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [column4] [real] NULL,
    [column5] [real] NULL,
    [column6] [real] NULL,
    [column7] [real] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]"

}
```

Even better, we don't have to specify the 4 if there is a way to tell Powershell that only the first x amount of columns are `varchar`, while the rest are `real`.

Comment: Your pseudocode is an excellent start. How do you think you can get the column list into a list that you can iterate over so that your `foreach` would work?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid something like 
$csv = Import-CSV $csvFile;
$csvHeaders = ($csv | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty).name;
foreach($header in $csvHeaders) {
...etc...} so thats getting the headers, which is pretty straight forward, but how to dynamically specify "for the first $x columns, create table column as varchar type, and for the rest, real type."

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I editted my post with the list of headers

Comment: Personally I would use a counter inside the `foreach` to decide which datatype should be emitted for each iteration. There's probably a smarter way though.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid ya at this point im getting hopeless trying to find a good way to do it lol. I am looking through c# code since its possible to run c# code through powershell...i literally cant find any example online with powershell to create table from a file...i did find examples with c# though, but they have just 1 predefined data type, unlike my requirement which has 2 data types at least :/

Comment: To create a table you just have to run that create table script against the sql server. Prior to this you need to build a suitable create table statement in a string. This is of course driven by your `foreach` loop. Can you see how you can build a suitable `create table` statement inside your `foreach`? You don't need C# at all for this.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid hmm...maybe i can utilize `| select -First $x` instead of counter. but i think that would require 2 foreach loops, one for the first 3 columns and one for the last 4 columns...maybe the first for loop i create the table, and the second for loop i update the table to add the remianing columns with real type?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid the problem is i need to create the columns dynamically based on the headers in the csv file. here for the sake of simplicity i specified the columns 1 by 1, i.e. column1, column2, etc...but my csv file contains over 80 columns, and i need the sql to create the columns dynamically...and i cant find an example of that with powershell...which is why i was looking into c#

Comment: Doesn't `$column` contain the column name? You append it to your create table string inside each iteration of your `foreach`

Comment: You only need one for loop which appends column names to a string containing `'CREATE TABLE [dbo].[$csvfile.name]('`. The names of the columns come from `$column`. The data types of the columns are derived from the position in the loop compared to input parameters

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid but the problem is, how do i dynmically create the columns from $column in the CREATE TABLE statement? in my post, i am specifying the columns hardcoding each one for the sake of simplicity, but the script has to create them dynamically inside the CREATE TABLE statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, just guidance, showing an inelegant brute force method that probably has syntax errors. There are PS guns that can probably reduce this to three lines.

Extending your pseudocode:

```
$csvfile = .\Fact.csv
$csv = Import-CSV $csvFile
$csvHeaders = ($csv | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty).name

$query="CREATE TABLE [dbo].[$csvfile.name]( "
$index=1
foreach ($column in $csvHeaders) {
  $query=$query+"[$column] "
  if($index -gt $varcharendposition) {$query=$query+"real, "} else {$query=$query+"varchar(50), "}  
  $index++
}
$query=$query + ") "

Query $query
```

This will be full of errors, but try it and troubleshoot each error or bug as t arises. Then you can post your answer and accept it.

Comment: I ended up using Smo objects thanks to this post here: https://www.codykonior.com/2016/01/21/constructing-a-sql-server-2016-temporal-table-using-smo/